# Calling an object within a class

Tags: python

I am trying to call the `.id` and `.importance` objects from the `Employee class`, but am presented with the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'id.` It seems that I am initializing all the items that I am supposed to, but am unsure of where the break is.

Here is the original code. It is actually a solution to the following [LeetCode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/employee-importance/).

Ultimately, I just wanted to be able to run the code so I could understand the flow better, but am failing at that.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, id, importance, subordinates):
        self.id = id
        self.importance = importance
        self.subordinates = subordinates

class Solution:
    def getImportance(self, employees, id):
        emap = {e.id: e for e in employees}
        employee = emap[id]
        total_importance = employee.importance
        for id in employee.subordinates:
            total_importance += self.getImportance(employees, id)
        return total_importance

employees = [[1, 5, [2, 3]], [2, 3, []], [3, 3, []]]
id = 1
x = Employee(id, 1, employees)
t = Solution()
print(t.getImportance(employees, id))
```

Comment: You never use `x` anywhere, and that's the only `Employee` you create.  Just because you call a list `employees` doesn't mean its elements are `Employee`s (in your case, they are just lists).

Comment: Please, when you make an example here don't use a pointless `Solution` class.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: They did that because that's how the LeetCode example code is structured.

Comment: @martineau I understand. The people who have lazily promulgated this whole notion of a pointless `Solution` class from their materials in Java have done a great disservice to us all.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Since this LeetCode problem is for Java, it's somewhat understandable why the OP included it in their question. A better way to make your point might be to post a answer illustrating why or how it's unnecessary.

Comment: It is a straight copy/paste of the solution. I only included it for ease of reference. But if it is somehow insulting please let me know so I don't repeat it in the future. I was only trying to get it to output the correct output via the items below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding type annotations to your classes and running a type checker (`mypy`) helps point out where the misfire happened:

```
from typing import List


class Employee:
    def __init__(self, id: int, importance: int, subordinates: List[int]) -> None:
        self.id = id
        self.importance = importance
        self.subordinates = subordinates


class Solution:
    def getImportance(self, employees: List[Employee], id: int) -> int:
        emap = {e.id: e for e in employees}
        employee = emap[id]
        total_importance = employee.importance
        for id in employee.subordinates:
            total_importance += self.getImportance(employees, id)
        return total_importance


employees = [[1, 5, [2, 3]], [2, 3, []], [3, 3, []]]
id = 1
x = Employee(id, 1, employees)
t = Solution()
print(t.getImportance(employees, id))
```

```
test.py:23: error: Argument 3 to "Employee" has incompatible type "List[List[object]]"; expected "List[int]"
test.py:25: error: Argument 1 to "getImportance" of "Solution" has incompatible type "List[List[object]]"; expected "List[Employee]"
```

So we're passing the wrong kind of list to the `Employee` constructor on line 23 (it's a nested list, where we expect a single list of ints), and we're also passing that same wrong list to `getImportance` (it wants a list of `Employee` objects).

I think what you want to do is to make `employees` a list of `Employee` objects, which is just a matter of turning those three lists into `Employee()` calls:

```
employees = [Employee(1, 5, [2, 3]), Employee(2, 3, []), Employee(3, 3, [])]
id = 1
t = Solution()
print(t.getImportance(employees, id))
```

This typechecks without errors, and produces the output `11`, which is the sum of all the `importance` values in the org tree under id `1`.

Comment: Thanks that was it! I'd give an upvote but I don't have the rep for that. Additionally, for the variable total_importance, the initial value is 5, then 8, then finally 11. Is it correct to say that the initial values are not overwritten because the function is called recursively within itself?

Comment: Yes, each invocation of the function has its own local value of that variable.

Answer (score 2):

First, please keep your terminology straight.  `id` is a data value, not a function -- you cannot "call" it.  You can *access* the value.

The error message is quite correct: you pass a nested list of ints into `getImportance`, and somehow expect those integers to magically grow the attributes of `Employee` instances.  You have to create those.  A simple list has no `id` attribute.

True, you instantiate *one* `Employee`, but the you assign the entire list of ints as its subordinates.  From the naming, I think that you're trying to make a tree of the company reporting structure.  You have a non-trivial amount of programming remaining; you don't get that tree with a single instantiation and three assignments -- you need at least some iteration.

Answer (score 0):

`employees` is a list of lists, not a list of employees. `[1, 5, [2, 3]]` does not have an `id` attribute.

To fix it, you could transform your list of lists into a list of `Employee` objects. For example, including this line below your `employees = ...` helps:

```
employees = [Employee(*values) for values in employees]
```

or, equivalently,

```
employees = [
    Employee(id, importance, subordinates)
    for id, importance, subordinates in employees
]
```